# Testing Rack Middleware with RSpec to see if a "service" of the middleware loaded properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rack, middleware

I created a stock rails (4.2.1) application, and I was able to get the welcome page when I launch WEBrick.  However, I included a gem, `helios` in the Gemfile of the rails app.  I then read the instructions on the helios [README / documentation](https://github.com/helios-framework/helios#configapplicationrb) that the helios framework can be loaded into a rails app as middleware. So I modified the 
 **application.rb**

```
#application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module HeliosTest
  class Application < Rails::Application    
    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true


    config.middleware.use Helios::Application do
        service :data, model: '/opt/rails/Accounts.xcdatamodeld/Accounts 3.xcdatamodel/contents'
    end
  end 
end
```

restarted, WEBrick, and the rails app still launched and loaded the welcome page.  However when I looked at the schema for the rails app I noticed that it had not changed since I specified the datamodel in the application.rb.  I performed a `rake db:migrate` but that didn't alter the schema either.  It was suggested to me to test the middleware I am loading in the rails app, so I included RSpec testing framework to the rails app, but I am not sure how I would go about writing a test in RSpec that tests the `service` line in the application.rb because most stackoverflow questions concerning testing of middleware have to do with testing http requests.

*Note:* The rails app was created with a name `helios-test`.

Answer (score 0):

a middleware is not something that will change your schema or add to your migrations. if you RTFM you will see that the default is to create a new app using the helios command line interface.

if you want to use helios as a middleware, it's expected that you already have a helios app up and running, integrating it into another rails app.

Comment: I read the manual, and where in these instructions does it say that a helios app need to be created first?

https://github.com/helios-framework/helios#rails